# XSLT move element and add ID link

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<Metro>
<MeasurementList>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla</Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla</Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1213</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla</Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla</Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1214</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla</Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1215</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla</Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1216</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
</MeasurementList>
<References>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1212</Id>
        <Prop2>bla</Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla33</Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1213</Id>
        <Prop2>bla</Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla34</Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1214</Id>
        <Prop2>bla</Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla35</Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1215</Id>
        <Prop2>bla</Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla36</Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1216</Id>
        <Prop2>bla</Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
</References>
</Metro>
```

I have to move the `<Prop3>` tag from inside the `<AcqSettings>` to it's own element tag and add an `ID`. This `ID` also has to be added in another element so that those will be linked. Also, the `<Prop3>` might not be  present and one `<AcqSettings>` may have multiple links.

The expected file should be this.

```
<Metro>
<MeasurementList>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#33</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1213</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#34</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#33</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1214</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#35</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1215</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#36</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1216</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
</MeasurementList>
<References>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1212</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1213</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1214</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1215</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1216</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>33</Id>
        <Prop3>bla33<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>34</Id>
        <Prop3>bla34<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>35</Id>
        <Prop3>bla35<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>36</Id>
        <Prop3>bla36<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
</References>
</Metro>
```

I can generate the `ID` using 'generate-id', but I am not sure on how to add that to the new element and to the `<MeasurementX/Y>` elements for link. Also This has to be done in XSLT version 1.

Comment: Do you really need to use `generate-id` here? Could the `Id` elements of your `SensSettings` elements be of the form "1215-S"? (i.e. They have the same ID as the `AcqSettings` elements from which they derive, but are suffixed with a "-S")

Comment: It needs to be a different ID. In practice this will actually be a GUID, I can already make that, but I was simplifying it.

Comment: It might be an idea, since the <AcqSettingsRef> is also a GUID, to revert the guid or something similar like: '04af4da7-6eb0-4c1f-8d98-84faa9188c5f' becomes '7ad4fa40-0be6-f1cf-89d8-f5c8819aaf48'